# HTACCESS - Problems with non existent pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a php website made by me and it creates fake (non-existent) pages.
How can I remove them and return a 404 page with a redirect to the homepage?

**Fake pages that shows my homepage:**

```
/index.html?page=search&sRegion=Dublin
/index.html?page=search&sRegion=Edinburgh
https://www.example.com/?post_type=clients&p=1292
```

**This is my htaccess:**

````
RewriteEngine On

# add www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# external redirect to .html from .php request
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^./]+?)\.php$ /$1.html [R=301,L,NC,NE]

# internal rewrite to .php from .html if corresponding php exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch ".(ico|css|flv|js|gif|jpeg|png|woff|woff2|eot|svg|ttf|webp)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, no-cache"
</FilesMatch> ```
````

Comment: Your question's a bit confusing. On the web, a URL either serves some content or not, it is not "real" or "fake", so think in terms of *patterns of URL* and *what you want your URLs to do*. You also can't have something that is both a 404 and a redirect - those are different types of response. You could have a 404 page that *happened to have the same content as* your homepage, but again try to think of URLs and content, not "pages".

Comment: i don't have content on that urls and when i access  that urls i got my homepage.

Comment: As far as the web browser is concerned, you *do* have content on those URLs, it just happens to be *the same content* as your homepage. So, again, you need to decide what the *pattern* is which you want to change the behaviour for - is it any URL with a query string at the end? Or specific values in the query string, like particular regions?

Comment: I'm not using any pattern. I have only 5 pages: index.php, contact.php, form.php, about-us.php and map.php.

Comment: how can you remove something that does not exist?

Comment: or stopping something that don't exist with 404 page

Comment: Looking at the existing rewriting rules I'd say that the third block is responsible for what you observe. It takes care to rewrite any request to `/index.html` such that it is handled by `/index.php` (which probably is your "homepage"). If you don't want that, then remove that rule. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply add the following line to redirect all 404 (page not found) to your homepage.

```
ErrorDocument 404 [homepage]
```

For your case, assuming that your homepage is "/index.php", then add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```